# Sum Query Import Range function in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Need your help. I have 1 work document and 1 database document.

I put this formula in the work document

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL database document","Range"),"select sum(Col19) where Col1 = 'ABC' and Col2='01/01/23' label sum(Col19)''",0)
```

It works perfectly.

However, I need to remplace 'ABC' and '01/01/2023' by  the following information:
'ABC' by the cell B100 and '01/01/23' by J2 from the working document

For example:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL database document","Range"),"select sum(Col19) where Col1 = '"B100"' and Col2='"J2"' label sum(Col19)''",0)
```

But it doesn't work.

I need it to change when I downfill the formula.
B100 ==> B101 ==> B102 etc...
J2 ==> J4 ==> J5 ...

Is there any solution?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Eve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either of these and see how it goes:

If `Col2` and `J2` are proper date formats then try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL database document","Range"),"select sum(Col19) where Col1 = '"&B100&"' and Col2=date'"&text(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum(Col19)''",0)
```

If `Col2` and `J2` are just text-dates (tests `FALSE` for `ISDATE` Fx)

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL database document","Range"),"select sum(Col19) where Col1 = '"&B100&"' and Col2='"&J2&"' label sum(Col19)''",0)
```